# jquery datatable display No data available in table after creting table Row runtime(javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

i am trying to display table(`Jquery DataTable`) of data witch i created from `JavaScript`
but some how the table is display like this .

[image]
`Jquery DataTable` Properly display but the functionality is not working even if i do search then it display notification   `No data available in table`
Even if i do right click in page and `View Page Source` the new Row is not display their.
I don't no what is the problem hear i put the code of initialization for data table ,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers"
    });
});
```

code for insert row in table

```
$("#example").find("tr:not(:first)").remove();

 for (var i = 0; i < response.userListReturns.length; i++) {
    var table = document.getElementById("example"); 
    var thisRowCount = table.rows.length;                   
    var row = table.insertRow(thisRowCount);

     var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
     cell1.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell1.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell1.style.textAlign = "center";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell1.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";
     var element0 = document.createElement("input");
     element0.type = "radio";
     element0.id = "chkEditDelet"+i;
     cell1.appendChild(element0);

     var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);   
     cell2.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell2.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell2.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell2.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";
     cell2.innerHTML= i+1;


     var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);   
     cell3.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell3.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell3.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell3.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";//c4ffc4
     cell3.style.whiteSpace="nowrap";
     cell3.innerHTML= response.userListReturns[i].userName;

     var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);   
     cell4.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell4.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell4.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell4.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";//c4ffc4
     cell4.innerHTML= response.userListReturns[i].userAddress;

     var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);   
     cell5.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell5.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell5.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell5.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";//c4ffc4
     cell5.innerHTML= response.userListReturns[i].userPhoneNo;

     var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);   
     cell6.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell6.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell6.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell6.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";//c4ffc4
     cell6.innerHTML= response.userListReturns[i].education;

     var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);   
     cell7.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell7.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell7.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell7.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";//c4ffc4
     cell7.innerHTML= response.userListReturns[i].userLiginName;

     var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);   
     cell8.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell8.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell8.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell8.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";//c4ffc4
     cell8.innerHTML= '********';
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you are adding the rows manually and I am not sure that will work well with datatables. I recommend you read there api and if you insist on doing it this way you can use fnAddData, straight from the site the usage looks like:

```
var giCount = 2;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable();
} );

function fnClickAddRow() {
  $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
  giCount+".1",
  giCount+".2",
  giCount+".3",
  giCount+".4" ]
);

giCount++;
```

}

you can then still style the table through css.

Comment: i try so many other options but i think this is the only option i have thanks it's working ..

Answer (score 3):

Using `fnClickAddRow`, as @Shawn suggests, is the proper way to do it. However, I guess it requires som major changes in your code, and in fact it is not nessecary.

The main problem with your code is that for some reason `table.insertRow()` inserts the row in `<thead>`, not `<tbody>`. Datatables *requires* a `<thead>` section and can only handle *one* `<tbody>`-section.

The workaround is to create the `<tbody>` in code as well, and use `tbody.insertRow` instead of `table.insertRow`.

Second, be sure to initialize the datatable *after* *all* data is inserted. In the example below I call a function when the counter `i` has reached it's max, but you may want to do it in some other way.

The following code works, eg data is inserted by native javascript in a loop as above, and the resulting datatable supports sorting, counting and so on.

Test table, note without tbody!

```
<table id="example">
<thead>
<th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th><th>E</th><th>F</th><th>G</th><th>H</th>
</thead>
</table>
```

Script, almost as your loop above except I am addressing the tbody-variable instead of table. TIP : Use `insertRow(-1)` instead of `thisRowCount` etc, it is easier and does the same

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//create tbody section by code
var table = document.getElementById("example");
var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
table.appendChild(tbody);

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var row = tbody.insertRow(-1);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell1.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell1.style.textAlign = "center";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell1.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";
     var element0 = document.createElement("input");
     element0.type = "radio";
     element0.id = "chkEditDelet"+i;
     cell1.appendChild(element0);

     var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);   
     cell2.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell2.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell2.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell2.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";
     cell2.innerHTML= i+1;

     var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);   
     cell3.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell3.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell3.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell3.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";//c4ffc4
     cell3.style.whiteSpace="nowrap";
     cell3.innerHTML= 'userName'+i;

     var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);   
     cell4.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell4.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell4.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell4.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";//c4ffc4
     cell4.innerHTML= 'userAddress'+i;

     var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);   
     cell5.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell5.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell5.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell5.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";//c4ffc4
     cell5.innerHTML= 'userPhoneNo'+i;

     var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);   
     cell6.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell6.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell6.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell6.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";//c4ffc4
     cell6.innerHTML= 'education'+i;

     var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);   
     cell7.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell7.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell7.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell7.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";//c4ffc4
     cell7.innerHTML= 'userLiginName??'+i;

     var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);   
     cell8.style.paddingTop = '4px';
     cell8.style.paddingBottom = '4px';
     cell8.style.textAlign = "left";
     if(i%2!=0)
     cell8.style.backgroundColor="#BAD6F7";//c4ffc4
     cell8.innerHTML= '********';

     //HERE you probably want some other logic
      if (i==4) {
        init();
    }
}

//init only when data is inserted to the table
function init() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers"
    });
}
</script>
```

This results in a **functional datatable without errors or warnings** :
[image]

PS : Guess `response.userListReturns[i].userLiginName` is a typo??

Comment: i try it but it's not working for me i don't no what's wrong , so i do as @Shawn suggests and it working thanks for replay .

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the table using `$('#example').dataTable().fnDraw();`