# jquery DataTable search and sort is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, datatable

I have an issues with datatable sorting and filter basically all the JS function not working.
I've already include the JS files. 
some details:
I'm connecting to the database to retrieve data in json.
The php file:('district.php')

```
    <?php  
  include_once('db.php');
  $db = mysql_select_db('mor_app',$con);  
  if(!$db){   die('Database selection failed '.mysql_error());  }   
  $sql = 'SELECT *FROM users';  
  $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);   
  $data = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $row_data = array(  
  'id' => $row['id'],    
  'date' => $row['date'],   
  'username' => $row['username'], 
  'Q1' => $row['Q1']    );  
  array_push($data, $row_data);  } 
  echo json_encode($data); 
  ?>
```

the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- DataTables CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <table id="table_id" class="display">  
 <caption>Try</caption>  
 <thead> <tr>  
 <th>ID</th>  
 <th>Date</th>  
 <th>user name</th>   
 <th>Q1</th> </tr>
 </thead>   
 <tbody id="tablebody"> 
 </tbody>
 </table>


       <script>

        $(function() {

  var url = 'district.php';    
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {     
  $.each(data, function(index, data) {     
  $('#tablebody').append('<tr>');      
  $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.id+'</td>');    
  $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.date+'</td>');  
  $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.username+'</td>');   
  $('#tablebody').append('<td>'+data.Q1+'</td>');    
  $('#tablebody').append('</tr>');    
  });   
  });

 });

      $('#table_id').DataTable();  


    </script>


  </body>
    </html>
```

now I can see the table but I just can't sorting or searching.
if I write something in the search box the table is empty. the same happen with sorting.
it say: No data available in table.
I thought it's happening because I'm retrieving data. any suggestion?
Thank a lot, Mor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I found is, you have to use DataTable's `fnAddData` function to add data in your HTML table. Otherwise, it is not adding your data which is being fetched on the fly. I tested with hard coded data in HTML which works fine, but whenever I tried to get data from other source through AJAX, it shows "no data found" or something.

I found the solution in [another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010818/jquery-datatable-display-no-data-available-in-table-after-creting-table-row-runt) .

I used AJAX for your solution, but the main catch is to use `fnAddData`.

Here is the solution (took help from above link) which works fine:

```
<script>
$('#table_id').DataTable();
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "district.php",
                            data: {data : ""},
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(result){
                                  data = JSON.parse(result);    
                                  $.each(data, function(index, data) {     
                                  //!!!--Here is the main catch------>fnAddData
                                  $('#table_id').dataTable().fnAddData( [
                                                                          data.id,
                                                                          data.date,
                                                                          data.username,
                                                                          data.Q1 ]
                                                                        );      

                                });

                            }

                    });

                });

    </script>
```

IMPORTANT: My answer considers that your PHP code is correctly returning data. I made some dummy array as suggested in the comments. My php file returns like this:

```
  $data = array(); 
  $row_data = array( 'id' => 1, 'date' => "2014-01-01", 'username' => "mou", 'Q1' => "muhahaha" ); 
  array_push($data, $row_data);   

  $row_data = array( 'id' => 9, 'date' => "2013-02-02", 'username' => "sadi", 'Q1' => "hii" ); 
  array_push($data, $row_data);   

  echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load jQuery BEFORE you load the datatables jQuery plugin:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Comment: now I get an error MSG : DataTable Warning : table id =example  - AJAX error . For more information about this error , please see http://datatable.net/tn/7.

Comment: and now I can't see data at all.

Comment: Are you sure that district.php is returning clean JSON?  Try replacing the code in district.php with the following to do a simple test:    `$data = array();
$row_data = array(
'id' => 8,
'date' => "2014-01-01",
'username' => "john",
'Q1' => "asdf"    );
array_push($data, $row_data);
echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: And, for a bit more information on your error: [http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7](http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7)  ... looks like either a bad response, or, not valid JSON. :-)

Comment: Hi John, thank you for reply. I tested it with your php code. and still get the same error msg. the Json retrieve good : [{"id":8,"date":"2014-01-01","username":"john","Q1":"asdf"}]          (I changed only the php file) what else can it be? Thank you, Mor

Answer (score 0):

add this statement to datatable definition on javascript

```
$('#table_id').DataTable({"sAjaxDataProp":"",});
```