# jQuery Datatable with Struts 2

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatables, struts2, struts-tags

I am using jQuery Datatable to display a table from database and iterating using `<s:iterator>`.

```xml
 <html>
 <head>   
    <link href="css/forum.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
            <link href="css/media/dataTables/demo_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="css/media/dataTables/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="css/media/dataTables/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="css/media/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
            <link href="css/media/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
            <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#display").dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "iDisplayLength": 5,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            });
        });
        </script>
   
 </head>
<body>
<table id="display">
         <thead>
             <tr><th>Title</th></tr>
             <tr><th>Desc</th></tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
           <s:iterator  value="travelBean"  status="i">
           <tr>
            <td>
               <s:url action="Display" var="DisplayLink">
                  <s:param name="title"><s:property value="title"/></s:param>
                </s:url>
              <a href="${DisplayLink}">
             <s:property value="Desc"/></a>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </s:iterator>
       </tbody>
</table>
</body>
<html>
```

In the output `<div>` which will form above the table from query to show entries and below for first, previous and next button are not appearing if I put `<tr>` `<td>` inside `<s:iterator>` and if I remove `<tr>` `<td>` then the `<div>`s are appearing but no table entries available in the table. Am not sure what will be the issue?

Comment: If you can't get data from database doesn't mean that you shouldn't try it on hardcoded data returned by the action.

Comment: Am getting data in tbody of the table but in another tbody it is showing "No data available in table". That is two tbody is displaying.Just like the image in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010818/jquery-datatable-display-no-data-available-in-table-after-creting-table-row-runt" but am not adding rows in jsp like this.

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you provide a code where getting it from the database?

Comment: String selectTravel="select * from travel ORDER BY travethreadcount DESC";
rs=stmtTravel.executeQuery(selectTravel);       while(rs.next()) {    title=rs.getString(2);
        travelDesc=rs.getString(3);
         travelBean.add(new TravelTable(title,travelDesc));
          
          }

Comment: in jsp am iterating using s:iterator to display title and and travelDesc

Comment: Do i want to return in "type="json" in struts.xml?

Comment: I am getting Json response in the browser and How to get JSON response in JSP? $(document).ready(function () in JSP is not calling to display the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table can be loaded from the HTML datasource. You should try the basic configuration, then add features. Because you might have a jQuery version mismatch.

```xml
<html>
<head>   
    <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#display").dataTable();
       });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <table id="display">
         <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>Title</th>
               <th>Desc</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tfoot>
             <tr>
               <th>Title</th>
               <th>Desc</th>
             </tr>
         </tfoot>
         <tbody>
           <s:iterator  value="travelBean">
           <tr>
            <td><s:property value="title"/></td>
            <td>
               <s:url action="Display" var="DisplayLink">
                  <s:param name="title"><s:property value="title"/></s:param>
               </s:url>
               <a href="${DisplayLink}">
                  <s:property value="travelDesc"/>
               </a>
            </td>
           </tr>
           </s:iterator>
         </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
<html>
```

The `travelBean` you iterate should have a getter and `TravelTable` should have getters for properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do i want to set "type=json" in struts.xml?

Comment: Thank you so much. its working but i got a warning "DataTables warning: table id=display- Requested unknown parameter '2' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4". What is this.

Comment: This means no data in the cell.